# How to pass a callback function to a StreamController

Tags: dart, dart-async

I was wondering something I'm creating a StreamController like that:

```dart
class {
  StreamController _controller = 
      new StreamController(onListen: _onListen(), onPause: _onPause(), 
          onResume: _onResume(), onCancel: _onCancel());

    Stream get stream => _controller.stream;
}
```

in an other class I invoke

```dart
var sub = myInstance.stream.listen(null);
```

and I'm really surprise that all the callbacks in the StreamController's constructor are triggered.

Is there an explanation for this behavior ?

Cheers !

Answer (score 4):

You should not add the parens `()`

```dart
class {
  StreamController _controller = 
      new StreamController(onListen: _onListen, onPause: _onPause, 
          onResume: _onResume, onCancel: _onCancel);

    Stream get stream => _controller.stream;
}
```

This way the expression you pass as argument to `onListen`, `onPause`, ... is a reference to a method/function. When you add parents the expression is a method/function call and the actual argument to `onListen`, `onPause`, ... is the return value of the expression.

Alternatively you could to it this way (I omitted arguments because I want to save the time to looke them up)

```dart
class {
  StreamController _controller = 
      new StreamController(onListen: () => _onListen(), onPause: () => _onPause(), 
          onResume: () => _onResume(), onCancel: () => _onCancel());

    Stream get stream => _controller.stream;
}
```

Comment: ohhhh shame on me... let's say it is because I learn Dart... Thx anyway